# alloc and init in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm assuming the definition of `alloc` goes along the lines of:

> Locates and allocates a block of memory for an object

And the definition `init` goes something like:

> Creates an object in the newly allocated memory block

I'm just trying to wrap my head around more regarding memory management and want to make sure that I'm getting this right..

Comment: So what's your question? :)

Comment: [`[NSObject alloc]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsobject_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/alloc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is sort of right.

It is right in principle. But `init` is actually not required to return the same, indentical, object. I never observed this (well, frankly, never checked for it either) but theoretically `init` may release the allocated object, allocate another one, initialize the second and return a refernce to the second one. 
Besides that detail you are totally right.

Comment: Want to see different objects from init? Take a look at NSArray, NSString, NSDictionary…

Comment: I thought there must be some. There must be a reason for that. Thanks @Chuck, I'll keep an eye on alloc/init of those types.